# JQuery Interesting Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my piece of code :

```
.................
 remProduct: function(e, $a) {
        var orderObj = {
            pid:   $a.parents('li').find('input=[name=pid]').val(),
            pk_id: $a.parents('div.packet').attr('id') || $a.parents('div.section').attr('id'),
            isSideCart: !!$a.parents('div.packet').length
        };
        var callBack = function(json) {
            if (json.success) { 
                if ($("div.sidebar").length) {
                    $("div.sidebar").replaceWith(json.body)
                } else if ($("div.content").length) {
                    $("div.content").html(json.body);
                }
            }
            front.rebindSideCart();
        };
        $.post(this.getPath() + '/remove-product', orderObj, callBack, 'json');
    },
.................
```

The idea is that I add or remove product from my Package. When I add a product and after that I want to remove it , it doesn't work and the firebug show me this error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input=[name=pid]

, **BUT** if i refreshed the page  it works. Can anyone explain me why ? Thx in advance !

Comment: May be if put your code in `document ready` or `onload` function, it should trigger `error` on every page `refresh`... other wise, it will trigger only when that statement executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `input[name=pid]` not `input=[name=pid]`

```
pid:   $a.parents('li').find('input[name=pid]').val(),
                   //--------------^ 
                   // remove = from this position as it is not a valid selector
```

**Syntax:**

```
$("element[attribute='value']")
```

**For egs:**

```
$("input[name='pid']")
```

Comment: thx man, I didn't realize it  that was the "=". I will accept your answer in less then 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `=` right after `input` inside `input=[name=pid]`:

```
pid: $a.parents('li').find('input[name=pid]').val(),
```

The correct syntax for **[Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** is: `jQuery("[attribute='value']")`.

Since your value is just a normal string then you don't need to wrap it inside double quotes, but if your value contain any of the meta-characters ( such as  `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, then it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\ or wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `=` operator after `input`.also wrap attribute value in quotes.it should be:

```
find('input[name="pid"]')
```

pid :

```
 pid:$a.parents('li').find('input[name="pid"]').val(),
```